# Archive multiple IOS xcode target in command line

Tags: xcode, command-line, target, xcodebuild, archiving

I have an iOS Xcode project that has several targets. The number of targets in the project will continue to grow as the project progresses and expands. When I create a new version, it is a pain to have to go through each target and manually create the Archive. I looked into how to archive multiple targets using the command line, but none of the answers spoke to what I was trying to accomplish. Any help and guidance is appreciated.

I believe that the following partial command is part of the solution:

xcodebuild archive

*archive: Archive a scheme from the build root (SYMROOT).  This requires specifying a workspace and scheme.*

Comment: hi, how did you do that finally?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to build it for CI server Manually
If you want to read all the schemes in a xcode project

```
xcodebuild -list | awk 'p && NF {print \$0";";} /Schemes:/ {p=1}' > schemeList.txt
```

This will put all your schemes in a text file. Then you have to read the text file manually to retrieve each scheme.

You can use the below command line to produce the archive

```
xcodebuild -scheme ${schemeName} -sdk iphoneos$sdkVersion  -configuration Release clean archive -archivePath ${archivePath}.xcarchive
```

And then the below xcode command to produce the ipa.

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath ${archivePath}.xcarchive -exportOptionsPlist exportOptions.plist  -exportPath ${exportPath}
```