# Archiving multiple targets simultaneously

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-targets

I have multiple targets for my iOS app. I want to archive all the targets simultaneously. I found this link but could not find anything in this 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582980/how-do-i-archive-multiple-targets-with-one-action-in-xcode-4)
.
Is there any way to archive and create different .ipa files simultaneously.

Comment: command-line tools with separate DerivedData paths. A popular way to script it is using Jenkins.

Comment: does this help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/41345948/6689101

Comment: thank you guys i will check above solutions

Comment: xcodebuild -list | awk 'p && NF {print \$0";";} /Schemes:/ {p=1}' > schemeList.txt 
I am getting syntax error for this. Is this changed now?

Comment: @Cœur can you give me some sample or example on how to do it?

Comment: I definitely recommend Jenkins for automation release/archiving process. It is even useful for test scenario. You can link it with a github repository, and make it scan whatever branch you want in order to start archiving.

Answer (score 0):

To build all the targets in a project you can add `-alltargets` to the end of the command

here is an example:

```
 xcodebuild -exportArchive -alltargets
```

but please take a look at [Documents Library](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html) for the required options `-exportFormat` , `-archivePath`